# How to list filenames with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, glob

I have multiple files with different suffix:

```
file_12
file_34
file_1245
file_4567
file_4
```

I only want to list the files whose suffix has four digits. I know I could do it like

```
ls -l file_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: File glob patterns are not the same as regular expressions, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on what you mean by *better*, which comes down to a *trade-off between efficiency and convenience*:**

- If by *better* you mean *more efficient*:

  - No: You've already found the most efficient way: globbing pattern
    `file_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` is resolved *by the shell, in-process* and passes the matching filenames to `ls -l`.
  - [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w), in a comment on the question, helpfully points to an article explaining the differences between *shell patterns* (globbing patterns) and *regular expressions*: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns
- If by *better* you mean *more convenient*:

  - Using regular expressions allows you to use quantifiers (duplication symbols), which simplifies the expression to `^file_[0-9]{4}$` or `^file_\d{4}$`, depending on the regex dialect.
  - This comes at the expense of requiring either:

    - a slow shell loop with conditionals using Bash's regex-matching `=~` operator - see [rob mayoff's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060627/45375)
    - involving *another external utility* that understands regular expressions, such as `grep -E` (`egrep`) - see [drewyupdrew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060513/45375).

      - A slightly more robust version, utilizing only `awk` as an additional utility:
        `ls -l | awk 'NF==9 && $NF ~ "^file_[0-9]{4}$"'`

At the end of the day, leaving efficiency considerations aside, neither regex-based solution *on balance* simplifies the task at hand, given the additional code that is required.

Thus, unless your matching logic is too complex to be modeled with a shell (globbing) pattern (not the case here), I suggest you stick with your original approach.

Comment: Exactly - `It depends on what you mean by better`.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's a glob pattern, but if you want to use regex you can use grep:

```
ls -l | egrep "file_[0-9]{4}$"
```

Keep in mind that the beginning of the filename is disregarded, so it would still match a file called `foo_file_1245`.

EDIT:  @[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) has suggested, and I agree, that this is a better approach if you must use egrep/regex:

```
ls -l | egrep '\sfile_[0-9]{4}$'
```

EDIT 2: Realized that the above statement would erroneously match a filename such as `someprefix file_1234`.  You can be extra safe and ensure you're using the egrep on only the last column (filename):

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | egrep "^file_[0-9]{4}$"
```

(but frankly OP, at this point, your glob solution is probably faster)

Comment: This matches `file_1234_blah`

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh you're right, we would need anchors.  I'll edit

Comment: ++, but `ls -l | egrep '\sfile_\d{4}$'` will give you the desired results without requiring an intermediate `awk` call.

Comment: @mklement0 oh interesting, I didn't know that. The additions you made to the regex, what do they do exactly?  I tried it, and wasn't able to get the desired output (my bash version: 4.2.25(1)-release).

Comment: @mklement0 Ah I think I see what you're doing.  So any number of space before `file` and then 4 digits, is that right?  How about this:  `ls -l | egrep '\s+file_[0-9]{4}$'`

Comment: @drewyupdrew: Correct. It didn't work for you, because of your `grep` implementation's dialect (which is unrelated to the Bash version): BSD `grep` understands `\d` to mean _digit_, but GNU `grep` doesn't (my bad); using `ls -l | egrep '\sfile_[0-9]{4}$'` should work on both platforms.

Comment: @mklement0 Ah I see, great thank you.  I'm here to learn!  Good stuff ++

Comment: @drewyupdrew My pleasure, and it's really great to see how you've responded to the comments on your answer in a friendly, collaborative manner. Can I suggest that you update your answer directly with the command that we arrived at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111168/discussion-between-drewyupdrew-and-mklement0).

Comment: @choroba just made me realize that `ls -l | egrep '\sfile_[0-9]{4}$'` may yield false positives, such as with a file named `someprefix file_1234`.

Comment: @mklement0 correct and it'll fail for the dreaded file names that contain newlines. As always - [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not a particularly better way to do it. The way you're doing it with a shell glob is easy to understand and almost certainly efficient enough.

Here's a worse way to do it: use the `=~` operator in the `[[` command to match filenames one at a time, like this:

```
for f in *; do
    [[ $f =~ .*[0-9]{4} ]] && ls -l "$f"
done
```

Here's another worse way: use the `find` command:

```
find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*[0-9]{4}' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Comment: ++, but there's no need for piping to `xargs`, `find -E . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*[0-9]{4}' -exec ls -l {} +` will do and is more efficient.

Comment: Because I'm old school.

Comment: I'm not sure what old-school means in this context, but `find`'s `-E` and `-regex` aren't POSIX-compliant, and neither is `xargs -0`. By contrast,  `find ... -exec ... +` _is_ (not sure in what version of the spec. it was introduced, however); in other words: among the features used, `find ... -exec ... +` should be safe to use and is both simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -e 'system "ls", "-l", grep /^file_[0-9]{4}$/, glob "file_*";'
```

Comment: Understood (and thanks for fixing), but you're launching `perl`, which is not lightweight, to then launch another shell instance from it, which strikes me as a heavy-handed approach. `ls -l | egrep '\sfile_[0-9]{4}$'` is simpler to compose and probably more efficient.

Comment: @mklement0: Processing the output of `ls` is dangerous. File names can contain spaces, newlines, etc.

Comment: I agree that parsing `ls` output is suboptimal, but _generally_ only with respect to _newlines_ embedded in filenames, which is very rarely a real-world concern, so let's leave that aside. Agreed that my `grep`-based solution could yield false positives. That said, the OP's own approach is both safe and efficient, albeit somewhat cumbersome due to not being able to succinctly repeat the expression `[0-9]` - compared to your solution, however, it is still simpler and more efficient overall.

Comment: I suppose `egrep '^file_[0-9]{4}$' <(printf '%s\n' *) | xargs -I{} ls -l {}` or `ls -l | awk 'NF==9 && $NF ~ "^file_[0-9]{4}$"'` would work robustly (except for embedded newlines), but these too reinforce the point that involving additional external utilities in this case is probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

`ls -l | grep file | grep -E '[0-9]{4}'`

Comment: This parses `ls`, which is [not a great idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and matches `1234file` as well.